# why pod with cluster ip service is reachable from host/node in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

when CLUSTER-IP is internal to cluster network, then why I am able to ping one of the cluster IP service from host/node where k8s installed. Have a look at ip 10.101.210.88 which is a cluster-ip and as per definition it must be only reachable from any other pod only but still I can reach it from my Ubuntu host/node machine

```
/root#kgs
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                           AGE
default       kubernetes                                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                           16d
kube-system   kube-dns                                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP            16d
ricinfra      service-tiller-ricxapp                      ClusterIP   10.98.94.194     <none>        44134/TCP                         7d7h
ricplt        aux-entry                                   ClusterIP   10.105.149.143   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                    7d7h
ricplt        r4-influxdb-influxdb2                       ClusterIP   10.110.14.243    <none>        80/TCP                            7d7h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-kong-proxy                NodePort    10.107.12.178    <none>        32080:32080/TCP,32443:32443/TCP   7d7h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-prometheus-alertmanager   ClusterIP   10.104.86.76     <none>        80/TCP                            7d7h
ricplt        r4-infrastructure-prometheus-server         ClusterIP   10.102.224.176   <none>        80/TCP                            7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-a1mediator-http              ClusterIP   10.105.45.1      <none>        10000/TCP                         7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-a1mediator-rmr               ClusterIP   10.108.188.147   <none>        4561/TCP,4562/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-alarmmanager-http            ClusterIP   10.111.239.130   <none>        8080/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-alarmmanager-rmr             ClusterIP   10.106.30.195    <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-appmgr-http                  ClusterIP   10.110.110.91    <none>        8080/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-appmgr-rmr                   ClusterIP   10.110.96.28     <none>        4561/TCP,4560/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-dbaas-tcp                    ClusterIP   None             <none>        6379/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2mgr-http                   ClusterIP   10.101.210.88    <none>        3800/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2mgr-rmr                    ClusterIP   10.101.245.34    <none>        4561/TCP,3801/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-prometheus-alpha      ClusterIP   10.97.95.213     <none>        8088/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-rmr-alpha             ClusterIP   10.100.36.142    <none>        4561/TCP,38000/TCP                7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-e2term-sctp-alpha            NodePort    10.108.215.136   <none>        36422:32222/SCTP                  7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-o1mediator-http              ClusterIP   10.96.196.67     <none>        9001/TCP,8080/TCP,3000/TCP        7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-o1mediator-tcp-netconf       NodePort    10.104.237.252   <none>        830:30830/TCP                     7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-rtmgr-http                   ClusterIP   10.105.27.42     <none>        3800/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-rtmgr-rmr                    ClusterIP   10.110.0.158     <none>        4561/TCP,4560/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-submgr-http                  ClusterIP   None             <none>        3800/TCP                          7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-submgr-rmr                   ClusterIP   None             <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 7d7h
ricplt        service-ricplt-vespamgr-http                ClusterIP   10.98.139.191    <none>        8080/TCP,9095/TCP                 7d7h
ricxapp       aux-entry                                   ClusterIP   10.99.152.66     <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP                    7d7h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-http           ClusterIP   10.99.222.68     <none>        8080/TCP                          25h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-bouncer-xapp-rmr            ClusterIP   10.97.149.3      <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 25h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-example-http                ClusterIP   10.101.14.166    <none>        8080/TCP                          2d11h
ricxapp       service-ricxapp-example-rmr                 ClusterIP   10.97.129.85     <none>        4560/TCP,4561/TCP                 2d11h
/root#
/root#
/root#ping 10.101.210.88    --------> this is a cluster ip and i am pinging it from my host/node machine 
PING 10.101.210.88 (10.101.210.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 10.101.210.88: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
^C
--- 10.101.210.88 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1019ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.032/0.046/0.061/0.014 ms
/root#
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to access the **ClusterIP** from **Kubernetes** worker nodes.

When you create the SVC in to Kubernetes with type **ClusterIP** it assigns the **Virtual IP** to **SVC**, Virtual IP address is accessible only within the K8s cluster.

Kubernetes uses the **IPTables** **rules** to forward traffic from **VirtualIP** to the PODs that the service is routing traffic to.

Kubernetes nodes are part of the Cluster they will be able to access the virtual IP. So **clusterIp** will be accessible from in cluster across from any of **worker node** but you won't be able to access it from **outside** of Cluster.

If you really want to go deep understanding the bridge, IP assignment, forwarding you can ref this nice article : https://dustinspecker.com/posts/iptables-how-kubernetes-services-direct-traffic-to-pods/

Comment: Thanks @Harsh Manvar    Now I have a problem here. In my node machine to ping pod, I want to user service name instead of cluster-ip. For that, I add service name and IP addr mapping in my nodes /etc/host file. But the service IP gets change when I reinstall k8s or when I reboot the node where k8s is installed. Do you have any suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: try with defining the `clusterIP: 10.43.11.51` to service config you are applying. i think with this way you will be able to get the static clusterip.

Comment: Sorry, did not get. What is this IP 10.43.11.51 ?  Is this any spacial ip which i have to use exclusively?  or any ip i can use which i give as value

Comment: you can set same IP or try with another minor change to value and let's check if it become static or not. i have never tried it with cluster IP but worked for with LB type so give it try if we can get static IP which not get change by mentioning that in yaml